# C# - Reading ListBox Items from another Class

Tags: c#, class, listbox, listboxitem

i'm new to programming. i'm trying to skill up writing a small program, but i'm stuck with passing form from class to class

here is the main class:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

public partial class Insomnia : Form
{
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         

        int outputValue = 0;
        bool isNumber = false;

        isNumber = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out outputValue);

        if (isNumber == false)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Error: That's not a number!");
        }

        else
        {

            if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(textBox1.Text))
            {

                listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(0);
                textBox1.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Present already!");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and this is the second class, always printing "listBox1 is empty":

```
    public class Metodi : Insomnia
{

    bool isAvailable;
    public void StartListen()
    {

        string[] arr = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];
        if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("listBox1 is empty!");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
            }
        }
ETCETC...
```

could you please show me where i'm doing it wrong? please speak easily because i'm new to coding (and i'm not english either :P)

thank!

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in this line "string[] arr = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];" How is the value of the count?

Comment: You have an instance of Type Insomnia running that want to communicate with an Instance of Type Metodi. So you have 2 forms at the moment right? Deriving Metodi from Insomnia doesn't make them the same instance they are two different objects. Both have their own ListBox. Or think about it this way. Insomnia and Metodi are both forms. Changing the Caption of one of it would you expect that the caption of both forms changes? No. That would be dumb.

Comment: mmmh ok, so how i'm passing the Listbox' Items from Insomnia to Metodi?

Comment: @nacho: the count value is always 0

Comment: A very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187575/how-to-transfer-selected-item-in-listbox-in-form2-to-textbox-in-form1-when-i-dou/20188134#20188134

Comment: What about organizing the array in Class Insomnia in button3_click event and passing to Class Metodi just that array? Will it work?